# Registering for notifications through the iPhone settings menu

Tags: objective-c, push-notification

To register for remote push notifications, I do something like this when the app starts up

```
 UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;

UIUserNotificationSettings *mySettings =
[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types categories:nil];

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:mySettings];
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

Along with the two delegate methods

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{
    NSLog(@"Register for remote notifications");
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication*) application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Failed to register");
}
```

I am able to acquire the device token which I can use to send push notifications.

My question is, what happens if the user originally declines the push notification prompt, and then goes back into the Settings of the phone and allows it. How do I get the device token then? The methods in the app delegate are not called.

I read that you should check to see if the user registered for push notifications each time the app is launched, but I would still need the device token to actually send the notification

Answer (score 0):

you can call your register for remote push notifications code in

> applicationDidBecomeActive

Based on apple documentation

> Calling  registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: results in iOS passing
>   the device token to the delegate immediately without incurring
>   additional overhead.

As to change notification setting user need to leave application and he will relaunch app once he changes those settings.